# How can I get the echo value from my php script using the JQuery Form Plugin?

Tags: forms, jquery, jquery-plugins, file-upload

I am used to get the echo message of the php script using the jquery ajax success function now  I use a plugin but I dont know how to use it

my approach is this but definitely do not work how should the right way? It just go directly to my php script

```
$(function() {
        $('form').ajaxForm(function() { 
           success: function(data){
                $('.new-profile-pic').html(data);
           }
        }); 
    });
```

HTML:

```
<p class="new-profile-pic">
            <!--Image should be here-->
        </p>
    <form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="upload-image.php" method="post">
            <input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="100000">
            <input class="profile-pic-name" name="uploadedfile" type="file">
            <input type="submit">
        </form>
```

PHP:

```
    <?php
$target_path = "uploads/";
$target_path = $target_path . basename( $_FILES['uploadedfile']['name']); 

if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploadedfile']['tmp_name'], $target_path)) {
    echo '<img alt="" src="'.$target_path.'">';
} else{
    echo "There was an error uploading the file, please try again!";
}
?>
```

Comment: You spelt success wrong, line 3 of the first block, "succes" should be "success"

Comment: sorry typo hehe but still it just directs to my php script

Answer (score 0):

You need to prevent the default action from occuring.

I believe this post has the answer you are looking for:

[How do I submit a form using jquery (ajaxForm plugin) to an external site but not reload to a different page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1267556/how-do-i-submit-a-form-using-jquery-ajaxform-plugin-to-an-external-site-but-no)

You need to use .preventDefault() on the submit event, or get it to return false on the form submit, e.g.:

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="upload-image.php" method="post" onsubmit="return false;">
```